# Extract coordinates from postgres

Tags: postgresql, geojson

I'd like to know how can I extract coordinates from "geom" column to this format:
For example: [-37.8839, 175.3745188667].

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to include your code attempt and details of what happens when you try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select 

   '[' || ST_X(geom) || ',' || ST_Y(geom)|| ']' as coords

    from pointtable
```

That uses the ST_X and ST_Y functions, but there are more, such as ST_AsText depending on what you're looking for.